# How to set current year in DatePickerDialog in Android?

Tags: android-studio, datepickerdialog

When my DatePickerDialog shows the year is set to '1900'. I Only know how to limit the past dates but I don't know how to limit the past years. What I want to happen is as follows.

ex. The user wants to input the Cheque/Check Date, I will only allow the past dates to the current year.

```
public void ChequeDate(View view) {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(PaymentHeader.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (year < mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (monthOfYear < 9) {
                        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-0"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-0" + dayOfMonth);
                        } else {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-0"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-0" + dayOfMonth);
                        } else {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    //dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    dpd.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get `current calendar instance` and from this you have to get `year, month and date`objects to pass as an arguments in the DatePickerDialog method and enable `setMinDate` method.
Check the following code now

```
public void ChequeDate(View view) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(PaymentHeader.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (year < mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                    if (monthOfYear < 9) {
                        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-0"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-0" + dayOfMonth);
                        } else {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-0"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-0" + dayOfMonth);
                        } else {
                            ChequeDateET.setText(year + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, year, month, date);
    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    dpd.show();
}
```